# Espresso perform click keeps waiting

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am trying to get a hang of Espresso (until now I think it is quite a PITA), and this code never ends:

```
@Test
public void Submit_ShouldShowWarningWhenNotBothSourceAndDestinationAreScanned() {
    try(ActivityScenario<ManualMoveActivity> scenario  = ActivityScenario.launch(ManualMoveActivity.class)) {

        onView(withId(R.id.btnSubmit)).perform(click());
        
        onView(withText(R.string.pleasescansourceanddestination)).
                        inRoot(isDialog()).
                        check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
}
```

It seems to be hanging on the `perform(click())` part, because when I replace it with this:

```
@Test
public void Submit_ShouldShowWarningWhenNotBothSourceAndDestinationAreScanned() {
    try(ActivityScenario<ManualMoveActivity> scenario  = ActivityScenario.launch(ManualMoveActivity.class)) {
        scenario.onActivity(activity -> {
            activity.btnSubmit_Click(null);
        });

        onView(withText(R.string.pleasescansourceanddestination)).
                        inRoot(isDialog()).
                        check(matches(isDisplayed()));

        }
}
```

it works fine.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Is it permanently stuck or does it time out after some time (about 45secs)? Do you have IdlingResources that are not set to idle? Do you have animations, like a progress spinner, running when this happens?

Comment: It does timeout, sometimes. There are no animation, just two `TextView`s and a `Button`

Comment: What is your `try()` doing? Looks like a custom function.